# $a_n>0,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent. Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}$ is also convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I considered dividing it into 2 parts and using comparison test.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}\\$

And we have $\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}<\frac{a_n}{n} ;\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2+m^2}<\frac{a_n}{n}$, respectively.

But somebody pointed out that adding parentheses, the maximum length of which is infinity, to series or rearranging the order of items is not always allowed, so does that mean that such an approach is wrong? If so, what's the correct proof like?

Comment: All terms are non-negative, therefore you can rearrange and group them as you like, it does not affect the convergence or the limit.

Comment: The objection raised by that person is invalid since $a_n$'s are positive.

Comment: Also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2680307/42969

Answer (score 1):

While the comments that absolutely convergent series can be rearranged freely are correct, that fact isn't even needed here. You can drop the assumption that $a_n > 0$ for all $n$. While absolute convergence of $\sum_n \frac{a_n}n$ is needed, it is only to allow you to use the comparison test, not because you have rearranged the series. You have not done so.

By definition for a convergent series $\sum b_m$ and given some fixed $n$,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m &= \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^N b_m\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sum_{m=1}^n b_m +\sum_{m=n+1}^N b_m\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n b_m +\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sum_{m=n+1}^N b_m\right)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n b_m + \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty b_m\end{align}$$
Indeed, you can drop the "convergence" assumption with the appropriate understandings. The convergence behavior of $\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m$ and $\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty b_m$ will always be exactly the same, except for the values of the limit points being offset by some fixed amount.

And if $\sum_n b_n$ and $\sum_n c_n$ both converge, then so does $\sum_n(b_n + c_n)$. This is one of the basic theorems about series.

Those two results are all that are needed to justify the part of your argument that was disputed.

I would say that the objection was without merit, but the fact that it caught you means it did have some merit - if just in getting you to improve your understanding of series.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Now I figure out that my confusion actually came from a misunderstanding that the 'rearrangement' happens in partial sums, thus I didn't understand why all these operations on partial sums are always allowed. The fact is that we rearrange series first and then we calculate partial sums accordingly, so no matter what we do with the partial sums, its result shall not alter since the arrangement of series has been fixed.

Comment: I don't think you have the right idea about rearrangements yet. Simply splitting a finite number of terms off the summation does not count as a rearrangement. In fact, rearranging you do that only impacts a finite number of terms doesn't change the limit or convergence. A simple of example of a problematic rearrangement: $\sum_n (-1)^n$ obviously diverges. But if you sum it by first pairing adjacent values, those pairs all sum to $0$, so you get an infinite sum of $0$s, which sum to $0$.

Comment: Well I had added quotation marks to the first rearrangement so what I referred to there was certainly not the same concept as the rearrangement of series. My professor told me that in an infinite sequence, any items with finite indexes are of little importance, so we can move or delete them freely without worrying the convergence of the sequence should change. I guess my vague expression in the first comment was to blame :(

Comment: Plus, "The fact is that we rearrange series first and then we calculate partial sums accordingly" was not referring to my solution to this problem. Now I feel a little stupid of me to have made things so complicated and confusing...